# Search by zipcode and show data within specific radius?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

Hi I have a database of the US, CANADA zipcodes with latitude and longitude.
I would like to implement search to show listings within specified radius.
How can it be done with Linq to Entity, C#

Thank you for examples

Answer (score 2):

This CodeProject article describes a method to calculate the distance between two zip codes and find all other zip codes within a radius of X miles of a specified zip code:

- [ZIP Code Utility](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zipcodeutil.aspx)

In the article is an Access database used but what you're going to use as your ORM and database isn't really the tricky thing here.

Comment: The idea similar but it's not linq and it's not up to date. I'm looking for solution using C#, LINQ and SQL Database

Comment: This example is using C#! Change the data layer with Linq to Entity as your ORM and SQL Server and you have it.

Comment: I asked for examples with linq and C#